# The bindValue is not working properly here

Tags: php, pdo, bind

```
if($_GET['s']<>''){

    $explode = explode(' ',$_GET['s']);
    $num = count($explode);

    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
        $busca .= " `nome` LIKE :busca$i ";//OR `district` LIKE :busca$i OR `city` LIKE :busca$i OR `area` LIKE :busca$i ";

        if($i<>$num-1){ $busca .= ' AND '; }

    }
    $buscar = DB::getConn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE $busca");
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
        $buscar->bindValue(":busca$i",'%'.$explode[$i].'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    echo "$busca";  
    echo "$explode[0]";
    $buscar->execute(); 

}
```

The echos work alright but the its not binding the values on $buscar it returns:

`nome` LIKE :busca0

It does not put the value from $explode[0] on $busca0 and the echo for explode is working properly...

Comment: I'm pretty sure bind_value is (always) working properly, though you might be using it wrongly "here"

Comment: did you tried to echo your created query? Show us the result

Comment: So any sugestions for using it right in this particular code?

Comment: echoing $busca the result is:

Comment: I don't understand what 'it returns' means here. Can you check the log and see how the query was _executed_?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Note that bindValue won't replace your query string prior to execution.

So, as someone else asked, you need to see what is actually being executed *at the DB server*.

You may have to turn on [MySQL general log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html%E2%80%8E) to do so.

**EDIT**: Since you can't use the general log, try [PDO debugdumpparams](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php)

--

Note that when feeding more than one parameter, your query base looks like this:

```
 `nome` LIKE :busca0  AND  `nome` LIKE :busca1  AND  `nome` LIKE :busca2
```

Which won't work unless all params are the same

Comment: yeah but im testing it with only one parameter and it dont work...

Comment: What DB driver are you using?

Comment: ... and turn this log off after checking is done. )

Comment: external hosting site does not allow me to see the sql logs :(

Comment: The try this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Comment: the debugdumpparams prints: "SQL: [47] SELECT * FROM users WHERE `nome` LIKE :busca0 Params: 1 Key: Name: [7] :busca0 paramno=-1 name=[7] ":busca0" is_param=1 param_type=2"

Comment: I feel very stupid right now, the problem was the collation that was case sensitive... Thanks for the help anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_GET['s']<>''){

    $explode = explode(' ',$_GET['s']);
    $num = count($explode);

    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
        $busca .= " `nome` LIKE :busca$i ";//OR `district` LIKE :busca$i OR `city` LIKE :busca$i OR `area` LIKE :busca$i ";

        if($i<>$num-1){ $busca .= ' AND '; }

    }
    $buscar = DB::getConn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE $busca");
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
        $buscar->bindValue(":busca$i",'%'.$explode[$i].'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    echo "$busca";  
    echo "$explode[0]";
    echo var_export($buscar->execute()->fetchAll(),true); 

}
```

bind will escape ' and you don't want that

Comment: You've just moved the % from the bound value to the query base, or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, but may not work, haven't tried sorry about that

Comment: Yeah, and it didnt worked :P just changed the return value to: `nome` LIKE '%:busca0%'

Comment: If it didnt worked like that it should have returned a PDO exception and it does not

Comment: What do you mean by `return value`? This function in your question doesn't return _anything_ at all; can you update the question adding the returning part of the code?

Comment: What does `echo $buscar->queryString` prints

Comment: return i mean when i do an 
echo "$busca";

Comment: echo $buscar->queryString prints: SELECT * FROM users WHERE `nome` LIKE :busca0

Comment: And it's its normal behavior. You'll see that param when you check the query itself on MySQL side, not in PHP.

Comment: Thats fine to see the param, did not excepted replacement